# Laravel : Set cookie for parent domain

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies, single-sign-on

I'm trying to build an SSO that will be shared between different applications with the same parent domain.
Say we have these  domains :

`sso.example.com`  Unified login page

`app1.example.com`  Some other application that will redirect to the login page

When I set `SESSION_DOMAIN=.example.com` in `.env` file of the SSO project, the cookie is indeed set in parent domain and is accessible from the APP1. However, the app will also set the other cookies such **XSRF-TOKEN**. I don't want to mess with parent domain cookies since there's also another independant app that uses that domain.

I tried to change the session.domain property on the fly of every request and change it back right after but it's not working. I guess the cookie is set when the response is finished which is not the case

```
Config::set('session.domain','.domain.com');
Cookie::queue('ssotoken', 'test', 60);
Config::set('session.domain','sso.domain.com');
```

So any workaround to set only the "ssotoken" for parent domain ? Or is there a way to access  `sso.example.com` cookies from  `app1.example.com` in Laravel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the cookie domain for a specific cookie at their fifth parameter, like this:

```
Cookie::queue(
    name: 'ssotoken',
    value: 'test',
    domain: '.domain.com'
);
```

Without named parameters your method call looks like this:

```
Cookie::queue('ssotoken', 'test', 0, null, '.domain.com')
```

It's a bit hard to see because `Cookie::queue` doesn't have [any documented parameters](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieJar.php#L141) since they're using the array spread operator, to either accept an already invoked `Cookie` class or allow to build a cookie without the setp of nesting two methods. The parameters supplied in the example correspond with those documented in the [`Cookie::make`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieJar.html#method_make) method:

```
Cookie::make(
    string $name,
    string $value,
    int $minutes = 0,
    string|null $path = null,
    string|null $domain = null,
    bool|null $secure = null,
    bool $httpOnly = true,
    bool $raw = false,
    string|null $sameSite = null
)
```

Comment: Tried Cookie::queue('ssotoken', 'test', 60, '.domain.com') but didn't work. The solution with named arguments can't work since I'm on PHP 7.3 with Laravel 7. Is there an equivalent solution ?

Comment: I've added an example for <= PHP 7.4.